# Proof ODE approximator isn't universally stable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

> Given the scalar ODE $y'(t) = \lambda y(t)$ we're given an
> approximation $$ y_{n+1} = y_n + P(\lambda h)y_n $$ where $$P(\lambda
>  h) = \sum_{k=1}^m \alpha_k \cdot (\lambda h)^k.$$ Note that $h >
>  0$ since its the step size and $P$ isn't constant. Now we want to show that for $\lambda <0$,
> that $y_n \to 0$ does not hold for all $h$ thus showing the ODE
> approximation isn't universally stable.

I've tried a few different approaches and I understand that if $\lambda < 0$ the $exp(-\lambda t)$ goes to 0 as $t$ goes to infinity. If we write
$$
y_n = \left(1 + P(\lambda h)\right)^n y_0
$$
then we see that
$$
| 1 + P(\lambda h) | \geq 1
$$
for $y_n$ to not tend to 0 although I'm not sure how to show this for $\lambda < 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select $h$ so large that $|P(h\lambda)| \geq 2$ and then $|1+P(h\lambda)| \geq 1$ from the triangle inequality. This is the generalization of the familiar situation that the Euler method for $y'=-y$ diverges if $h>2$.

Comment: Sorry I meant to $m$ not $\infty$ my bad. Ah okay, is there a criterion for $h$?

Comment: @JohnMiller Sure, you are just looking for $x_0$ (depending on $\lambda$) small enough that $P(x) \in (-2,0)$ whenever $x_0<x<0$. If $\alpha_1>0$ then such an $x_0$ exists (why?)